# get distinct word from textfile using python

Tags: python, filereader

I have a question regarding getting the distinct words from a textfile with about 14000 sentences. Now i'm trying to get every distinct word out of this text file so i don't have any doubles anymore so it would make the list a whole lot shorter for later processes for example hashing (otherwise i'd have the same hash multiple times).

I've looked into multiple options using python but the only think i found is a distinct word counter in python.

Is there any way i can do this?

Comment: Maybe you could try a `set`.

Comment: `with open(filename) as f: words = {word for line in f for word in line.split()}`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try to look at documentation and other stack overflow questions before asking questions of your own. Chances are if it's something as generic as this (ie. not adding duplicates), it has already been asked before.

```
#Psudocode
my_set = {'words go here'}
for each line in file:
    for each word in line:
        my_set.add(word)          #Word will only be added if it is not already present, a property of the set class
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your question hints at a good solution already:

"a textfile with about 14000 sentences"

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    data = f.readlines() # assuming each line is a sentence or the like
```

"get every distinct word" and "distinct word counter" and "hashing (otherwise i'd have the same hash multiple times)"

— depending on how its used, a `set` as hinted before would do this just for you. You mentioned hashing, and sets use hashes to localize objects into buckets.

```
unique_words = set()
for line in data:
    clean_line = line.rstrip()
    words = clean_line.split() # get all the words from one line
    unique_words.update(words) # throws these words into the set
```

The set will take care of dups for ya

Answer (score 0):

You can use the set functionality in python. A set does not allow the duplicate item to be added. Check out the below code.

```
word_set = set()
for line in open("test.txt",'r'):
    for word in line.split():
        word_set.add(word)
print(word_set)
```

File test.txt contains:

```
Hello World and again Hello World
```

Output:

```
{'Hello', 'again', 'World', 'and'}
```